# Laravel extend function with subdomain()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In view file I have following script

```
@extends(subdomain(), [
    'bodyExtraClasses' => 'page-login layout-full',
    'pageExtraClasses' => 'vertical-align text-center'
])
```

I am not sure this `subdomain()` extends which files into register.blade? Also there are two different register url but having same register template.

I know how to extend the master layout but this is new for me. I did some search about it but could not found good guideline or I am still fail to understand it. Also in this project we are using sub domain.

**Edited After 14 Hours**

After getting instruction from *@Mozammil* I have found the function in the helper (`functions.php`)

```
function subdomain()
{
        return str_before(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getDomain(), '.' . env('domain'));
}
```

Comment: This looks like the layout is going to change based on the subdomain. There must be a function called `subdomain()` defined somewhere.

Comment: @Mozammil Thanks let me find it where is the function. Kindly do let me know if you have any idea about it?

Comment: Is subdomain() a helper? Could you make it? Please pase the code of this helper.

Comment: If subdomain() is returning the name of subdomain you will need the blade files in /resources/views/  subdomain1.blade.php and subdomain2.blade.php (for eg.)

Comment: The `subdomain()` function isn't included in a standard Laravel installation. Are you using a CMS or other plugin functionality? You should share more about your project.

Comment: @AkenRoberts I have edited my question kindly check it please